# finding twitter4j retweet rate limit

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I would like to know how to find in java a rate limit for specific function in `twitter4j`

```
twitter.retweetStatus(lstatusId);
```

I would like to know how to check if im passing the rate limit for retweeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add following piece of code to check for rate limit status, you would need to provide for specific url, for example if you are fetching "statuses/retweets_of_me" then your url-to-get-rate-limit-status-of would be "statuses/retweets_of_me"

You would need to find mapping to Rest API url for each of your streaming API call and use that url to get the rate limit status.

```
if (twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get(<<url-to-get-rate-limit-status-of>>).getRemaining() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Adding wait of - " + twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get(<<url-to-get-rate-limit-status-of>>).getSecondsUntilReset() + " seconds");
        Thread.sleep(twitter.getRateLimitStatus().get(<<url-to-get-rate-limit-status-of>>).getSecondsUntilReset()*1000);
    }
```

Hope this helps.